# Trying to connect to Dropbox using its Python API, but failing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dropbox

This is in Google App Engine. I'm trying to load the Dropbox API Request Authorization page at the beginning, then redirect to my OtherPage when the "Allow" button is clicked, and finally use client for other purposes. Here's my code so far:

```
import webapp2
import cgi
import urllib2
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# app key and secret from Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'key'
app_secret = 'secret'
access_type = 'dropbox'

sess = session.DropboxSession(app_key, app_secret, access_type)
request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token, '')
        self.redirect(url)

class OtherPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        try:
            self.response.write('<html><body>Testing:')
            access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
            client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
            ...(other code)...
            self.response.write('</body></html>')
        except:
            self.response.write('<html><body>Incorrect authorization code, please try again.</body></html')
```

None of the code in the try block after

```
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
```

is executed, and the program goes to the except part. It doesn't crash, just writes "Incorrect authorization code, please try again" to the Other web page.

Edit: What the server prints to command line:

```
INFO     2013-08-13 03:43:50,755 sdk_update_checker.] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-08-13 03:43:51,233 sdk_update_checker.] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2013-08-13 03:43:51,252 api_server.] Starting API server at: 
INFO     2013-08-13 03:43:51,270 dispatcher.] Starting module "default" running at: 
INFO     2013-08-13 03:43:51,273 admin_server.] Starting admin server at: 
INFO     2013-08-13 03:43:57,594 module.] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2013-08-13 03:44:01,062 module.] default: "GET /other?uid=162326169&oauth_token=Qoxo0R0Ki3q5NzWM HTTP/1.1" 200 118
INFO     2013-08-13 03:44:01,224 module.] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 154
```

Edit 2: Solved. After removing the try and exception blocks and just running what's in the try block, it took issue with the line

```
client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
```

After renaming the first client to something else, it worked.

Comment: At a minimum you should include the stacktrace, you have a bare except in your code so who knows what the exception is.

Comment: Please print the information about the exception.  This might help.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1715206

Comment: That's all the information about the exception there is. I wrote it myself.

Comment: The way you handled the exception is a really bad idea.  You should log the real exception, then you will have a much better idea of why something has failed.