# Saving file to jpg format

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm reading a folder with different image types and if they are not in the *jpeg* format then to save them in this format.

But when I try to save them in this format I get an **IOError**. I've confirmed that I am reading the file contents ok:

I'm trying to do this using the **PIL** library. This is the code:

```
folder = os.listdir("C:\***\***\***\\abc")
for infile in folder:
    f,e = os.path.splitext(infile)
    newFile = f + ".jpg"
    if infile != newFile:
        try:
            Image.open(infile).save(newFile)
            print "DONE"
        except IOError:
            print "Cannot convert file", infile
    else:
        print "File: " + f + " is in jpg format"
```

Checking output here

```
folder= os.listdir("C:\***\***\***\\abc")
print folder
for infile in folder:
    print infile
```

Currently I get the error message:

```
Image.open(infile).save(newFile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'empire.bmp'
```

This is pretty much the code from the resource at: http://effbot.org/imagingbook
/introduction.htm

Thanks

Comment: It works perfect on my machine. What error message have you got ?

Comment: No specific error...just executing the except branch

Comment: Use this to get the error message and traceback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715198/exception-message-python-2-6/1715222#1715222

Comment: Thanks for that..I'll edit my question with the traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be your `infile` was not recognized, try this :

```
originFile = 'C:\***\***\***\\abc\%s' % infile
Image.open(originFile).save(newFile)
```

Comment: Yes...that worked. Must have not been picking up the file path properly. Thanks

Comment: oops I forgot to change `newfile` to an absolute path too, and it should be. @user94628

Answer (score 1):

Try using [pgmagick](http://pythonhosted.org/pgmagick/index.html) library, I always used for this task and it always did the job for me. It's really easy to use. Read the image whatever format it has and save it as jpg (by replacing the extension in the path)